# Order of displaying answers for a question

Tags: discussion, support, sorting

Have a look at below question :

[How to check if two words are anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045640/how-to-check-if-two-words-are-anagrams)

I don't know the criteria for showing order of answers but you can see that lot of negative score answers are hiding good answers.

I think that negative score answers should be moved down and positive score answers should move up.

Do you also have same thoughts?

**EDIT:**

I have gone through proposed answer & other answer linked to my question. Just have a look at current question. Default is sorted on "Active".

```
First answer : answered Jun 8 '13 at 23:25, commented on : Oct 29 at 22:25
Second answer: answered May 26 '14 at 9:21, edited today 
Third answer :answered Oct 11 at 6:03,edited today
Fourth answer: answered Jul 29 at 15:24, edited, Sep 14 at 6:52
```

Still these answers are not in right order of "Active"

Comment: Please don 't shorten _"Positive"_ as _"+ve"_ and _"Negative"_ as _"-ve"_...

Comment: "First answer" is accepted, these are always on top (except for accepted [meta-tag:self-answer]s), no matter what sort order you pick

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the shown answers are sorted by vote count:

[image]

Comment: That is fine. Can't it be default criteria?

Comment: It is. You probably (accidentally) clicked one of the other 2.